# Cannot extract time from a cell with datetime.datetime

Tags: python

```
cmbd['FinishTime'] = [d.time() for d in cmbd['Finish']]
```

Code not working giving the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Column contains

```
2018-01-02 08:21:54
```

the same formula works for another column

```
cmbd['StartTime'] = [d.time() for d in cmbd['Start']]
```

with the following values in the column

```
2018-01-01 08:58:00
```

Comment: The cells must contain different types. You need to look at how those cells are created. There is not sufficient information in this question to know the issue. print out `cmbd` before the list comp and iterate over it examining the types. Are they what you expect?

Comment: Show us the column definition, and all column values, for `cmbd['Finish']`.